# My wordpress plugin is beeing called twice

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress plugin, and by debugging, I noticed its being called twice on each request. My plugin code is like this:

```php
class Br1E_EngenhariaPlugin{
   (...)
}

new Br1E_EngenhariaPlugin(); // A breakpoint here is called twice on each request
```

Debugging the code I see that the problem is that the `wp-load.php` file is being called twice. The first time the callstack started at `index.php`:

[image]

If I hit continue, it will stop again at the same breakpoint, this time the callstack started at `wp-cron.php`:

[image]

I tried to make my class a singleton, by using a static variable to ensure the class is loaded only once:

```php
class Br1E_EngenhariaPlugin{
    public static function LoadOnce() : Br1E_EngenhariaPlugin
    {
        if (self::$pluginInstance == null)
            self::$pluginInstance = new Br1E_EngenhariaPlugin();

        //register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($br1Engenharia, 'install') );
        return self::$pluginInstance;
    }
    (...)
}

Br1E_EngenhariaPlugin::LoadOnce();
```

But it didn't work. The `$pluginInstance` static variable is null on the second time it's called, it's like it's a different request.

Answer (score 0):

And yes, it is a different HTML request called from `spawn_cron()` in the file `wp-includes/cron.php`:

```
$result = wp_remote_post( $cron_request['url'], $cron_request['args'] );
```

Here `$cron_request['uri']` contains `http://your-site.com/wp-cron.php`. And you can see it in the second call stack.

`wp_cron` in the file `wp-includes/cron.php` is hooked on every' init' event. Then, if any cron jobs are to be executed, `spawn_cron()` is called, producing an independent HTML request to the site.

Comment: And can i disable it ? How do i do that? I'm on a local server in my development machine, so less process running could mean faster running site for development

Comment: You can disable cron fully by adding the line `define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON`, true );` to the `wp-config.php` before `That's all, stop editing!`, but I have no idea what kind of side effects this could have for your test site.

Comment: Having cron working on every request is a clear signal that something is wrong with your theme or plugins. Cron jobs are scheduled too often, or an event created on each page load to be executed `now`. Deactivate all plugins, change theme to standard and check. Use `wp cron event list` to see all scheduled events.